# How to run Java public static void main from Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

[Please click this image for the description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sd7U.png)

Hi guys, so my homework is asking that I run my program on command prompt which would be Terminal for Mac users like me.

How would I run this on Terminal? How to I access bin?

Also for the >java Echo "echo this string"

How can "echo this string" be accessed as arg[0] and arg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sd7U.png)? Which is which for arg[0] and arg[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sd7U.png)???

Comment: can you put what is needed here, that link may got removed

Comment: And as you are also asking about eclipse: https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/eclipseCommLineArgs.html

Comment: can you up the answers if you think they were helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html the official Oracle techno document

```
//A Very Simple Example
class ExampleProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("I'm a Simple Program");
  }
}
```

**Compiling the Program**

> The Java compiler is invoked at the command line on Unix and DOS shell
>   operating systems as follows:

```
  javac ExampleProgram.java
```

**Interpreting and Running the Program**

> The Java interpreter is invoked at the command line on Unix and DOS
>   shell operating systems as follows:

```
java ExampleProgram
```

> At the command line, you should see:

```
I'm a Simple Program
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your Echo.java file, compile it with `javac Echo.java`.

After that, you can run the generated Echo.class with `java Echo "echo this string"`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can "echo this string" be accessed as arg[0] and arg1? Which is which for arg[0] and arg1???

you just `System.out.print` them in your code and that's it.

on how to start your app from the terminal use

```
java MyClass
```

if it's a class or

```
java -jar MyClass.jar
```

if it's a jar file

and you can add the `Sting [] args` in your command like this

```
java MyClass first_arg second_arg ect...
```

the array is seperated by white spaces and it's just accessed within your main with the `args[]` array .

here is what your Echo class might look like :

```
public class Echo
{
public static void main (String [] args )
{
for (String str : args )
{
System.out.print(str +" " );
}
}
}
```